# Animation Nodes. Distribute objects based on distance

Tags: animation-nodes

I have an Animation Nodes tree where I distribute characters based on random values on Y and Z axis as you can see below.

[image]

But viewing from that camera angle (the perspective view) the upper part of the picture is too dense.

[image]

So as long as I use the random function it distributes the characters "evenly" in space, but I need a control to decrease the amount of the objects based on the camera distance gradually. Is it possible with Animation Nodes?

Comment: A work around not using animation nodes (until someone has a better solution) would be to use a people particle system and weight paint distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a quite simple solution. The *Map Range* node has an interpolation input where we can plug the *Interpolation from Curve Mapping* node. So we can adjust the mapping of a random value with a curve. See below:

[image]